# Determine if the function $f(x)=3\tan x+\sin(4x)$ is even, odd or neither

Tags: functions

Determine if the function $f(x)=3\tan x+\sin(4x)$ is even, odd or neither.

Here is the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rajwrpt60q.

For the domain of the function we must have $\cos x\ne0\iff x\ne\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. How do I determine if this gives a set symmetrical about $0$ which is needed for a function to be even or odd?

We also have $f(-x)=\tan(-x)+\sin(-4x)=-\tan(x)-\sin(4x)=-f(x)$. So we are only left with the aforementioned question.

Comment: Plot the points for $k$ from $-3$ to $3$ and see if that gives inspiration.

Comment: You found out that $f(-x)=-f(x)$. If $f(x)\ne 0$ somewhere, then this rejects the possibility that $f$ is even.

Comment: @peterwhy, but we are sure that if $x\in D_x$, then $(-x)$ is also from $D_x$, where $D_x$ is the domain of the function $f(x)$?

Comment: @RossMillikan, I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you clarify it for me?

Comment: To continue on your progress about the domain, $\cos(-x) = \cos x$, so $$\cos(-x)=0 \iff \cos x = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, hence it is an odd function.

$$f\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right)=3\tan\left(-\frac\pi4\right)+\sin(-\pi)=-3 $$

$$f\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)=3\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\sin(\pi)=3  \ne f\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right).$$

Hence it is not an even function.

Notice that if $\cos(x)=0$, then $\cos(-x)=0$ since cosine is an even function.